# jquery - selecting a drop down text that will remove a value from another drop text

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

```
$(function () {
    $("#Dropdown1").change(function () {
        var selectedvalue = $('option:selected', $(this)).text();
        alert(selectedvalue);
        $("#Dropdown2").find("option[text=" + selectedvalue + "]").remove();
    })
});
```

Dropdown1
A
B
C

Dropdown2
B
C
D

When I select the text "B" in dropdown1, the text "B" should be deleted in Dropdown2

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle code?

Comment: remove by value, not text.

Comment: I want it to be removed by text, not select value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8V8RN/1/)

```
 $(function () {
    $("#Dropdown1").change(function () {
        var selectedvalue = $('option:selected', $(this)).text();
        alert(selectedvalue);
        $('#Dropdown2').find('option:contains('+selectedvalue+')').remove();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
   $(function () {
    $("#Dropdown1").change(function () {
        var selectedvalue = $('option:selected', $(this)).text();
        alert(selectedvalue);
        $("#Dropdown2").find("option[value=" + selectedvalue + "]").remove();
    })
});
```

Comment: I don't see any difference, it is same as the question I placed

Comment: option[text to option[value

Comment: @user3080252 he is removing it by value, not text.

Comment: I want it to be removed by text, not by value